# "PANIC: Could not find..." when I try to run emulator on Android Studio on ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, android-virtual-device

When I try to run the emulator on Android studio it prints: "PANIC: Could not find Nexus_5_API_21.ini file in $ANDROID_AVD_HOME nor in $HOME/.android/avd" and nothing happens.

I have tried setting the ANDROID_AVD_HOME variable with no luck. Where should I set the environment variables? I have tried to set ANDROID_SDK_HOME too, but I dont know where to set it.

I am using Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 and Android Studio 1.0.1

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a workaround.

It's possible that the files aren't present in the `$HOME/.android` at all in Linux. The files should be present in `/root/.android/`. So copy everything from `/root/.android/` to `~/.android/` (or `/home/username/.android/`) and it should work!

Comment: Feels like an android studio bug to me. shouldn't it be defaulting the location to /home/username/ ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary that you move your files to that direction. If you are in Linux, you just need to run the android studio with super user permission.

Run it in the terminal after you put

```
sudo su <PASSWORD>
```

And then run your android studio.

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this problem is to copy the file's emulator which exited and rename it to the name of the new emulator; that is, the name of the emulator Android Studio is trying to run.

I assume you've installed the Eclipse ADT which contains an emulator.

Example:

1. `cd .android/avd/`
2. `ls -al`
3. `cp <old emulator name>.ini <new emulator>.ini`
4. Run the emulator in Android Studio by the AVD